# vector expanding and thread routine

Tags: c++, vector

I have this problem, there is a `Manager` which will create several `Worker`s to do some job, each worker will fire a thread, code looks like this:

```
void Manager::create_workers(int n)
{
    _workers_vec.push_back( Worker() );  //save workers in Manager::_workers_vec
    _workers_vec.back().start();  //call the newly created worker's start() to fire a thread
}

void Worker::start()
{
    pthread_create(&_thread_id, NULL, routine, this);  //here is the problem
}
```

The problem is that, `Worker`'s thread routine will take `this` as the routine argument in order to use some data member of `Worker`, but the `Worker` object is created and pushed back into `Manager::_workers_vec`, when `_workers_vec`'s capacity is not enough to hold more `Worker` object, it has to expand, during which old `Worker` object will be copied to newly allocated space, and then be destructed.

This will cause `Segment fault`, because the thread `routine` is running and using `this` as the passed in argument, and `this` is destructed during `vector`'s expanding.

Besides changing `_workers_vec` from `vector<Worker>` to `vector<Worker *>`, any better idea about how to deal with `routine`'s passed in argument?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think you already got the answer - pointers. Apart from that but similar, is to involve some kind of smart pointer, like boost::shared_ptr, or std::shared_ptr (if you can use the C++11 standard).

Comment: Encapsulate created `Worker`s in a `shared_ptr`object and then push_back the `shared_ptr` object into the vector?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on why you would like to use a vector. You can use a std::deque instead, a deque doesn't reallocate when it grows, the data is stored in chunks and a new chunck gets added to the deque when it grows beyonds its capacity.

A deque's data therefore isn't contiguous so if that is a concern you can use a std::array if you know the size of the container at compile-time, or if you know it at runtime you can use std::vector.reserve() to allocate the required amount of memory.

You can also use a linked list if you don't need constant time access to the container.

Alternatively you can use a vector with std::unique_ptr if you're in C++11 or std::shared_ptr.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` (from either C++11 or Boost) is the way I would solve this. (Assuming I couldn't change the design to avoid the problem entirely.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, you mean pass in routine a `shared_ptr` as the argument?

Comment: No I think he means `_workers_vec.push_back( make_shared<Worker>() );` Leave Worker::start() as is. Use unique_ptr if you don't require sharing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I wish you explained why you don't want vector. I believe every solution will use pointers at some point. You could change the container to be a list instead of vector but this essentially means using pointers and allocating every Worker on the heap.